# How to get the source of an Image - not the standard way

Tags: javascript, regex, image

Using Javascript;

I have an image src for example `src = "images/folder1/image1.jpg"`

The src folder exists in a gallery section of the website at "http://www.example.com/gallery/index.php"

The full image src when I use

```
var images = doucment.getElementsByTagName("img");
var source = images[0].src;
```

this outputs: "http://www.example.com/gallery/images/folder1/image1.jpg"

I want it to output: "images/folder1/image1.jpg"

Is this possible using regExp or an equivalent? If so how?

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those occasions where there is a difference between an HTML element's **attributes** and its **properties**.

Attributes are (generally speaking) the values specified in the HTML. Properties are the attribute values standardised to be consistent (e.g. relative URLs are transformed into absolute URLs). Generally it's more useful to work with properties, but on this occasion you want the attribute value.

To do this, we use the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) method:

```
var source = images[0].getAttribute('src');
```

This gets the value specified in the HTML, rather than the computed value used in the DOM.

Comment: Took the time to explain the difference in simple understandable terms. Put my answer to shame! +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) instead to get the raw value from the HTML:

```
var source = images[0].getAttribute("src");
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp6W4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, you need to get the element, and put:

```
.attr("src");
```

or in tradicional javascript:

```
images[0].getAttribute("src");
```

this will gave you the exactly text in the html.